# Deleting or export a full module in Laravel

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-modules

Let's say that we made a complete app module in Laravel:

> php artisan make:model Post -a

Is there any way to delete or export this module and install it into another Laravel framework?

Comment: I think you mean *model* (not module)? AFAIK the command you show just creates a few flat files - `app/Post.php` and `database/migrations/something.php`, and ... that's all?  There is not much to export really.  You can simply copy those 2 files anywhere if you want to "export" that model.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: no i meant 'module ' .. as a part of app that can used into work in other laravel projects.@Don'tPanic